# Using printf in bash

Tags: bash, printf

When using printf in bash, does one always have to supply a format string as here.

```
printf "" "V01 Oct 2021"
```

Or would `printf "V01 Oct 2021"` still be ok?

Answer (score 6):

I would strongly recommend you use a format string with `printf`. For example,

```
printf '%s' 'V01 Oct 2021'        # V01 Oct 2021
```

If you use an empty format string, you'll get an empty result because there is no instruction to print the parameter:

```
printf '' 'V01 Oct 2021'          # (nothing)
```

In this next case, since your string does not contain any format control characters you can use just a format string with no parameter value:

```
printf 'V01 Oct 2021'             # V01 Oct 2021
```

However, if you are interpolating a variable it should *never* go into the format string, just in case it starts with `-` or contains `%` or `\` characters (or other characters whose encoding contains that of `%` or `\` with most `printf` implementations including bash's builtin one). For example,

```
d=5; a="Increase by $d%"

printf "$a"                       # -bash: printf: `%': missing format character
printf "$a\n"                     # -bash: printf: `\': invalid format character
printf '%s\n' "$a"                # Increase by 5%
printf 'Increase by %d%%\n' "$d"  # Increase by 5%
```

Notice in the second of these examples that `\n` is not in itself invalid, but the `%` symbol at the end of `$a` confuses `printf`.